# Dual booting ubuntu and manjaro: manjaro only boots in initramfs fallback kernel

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, dual-boot

I had ubuntu installed on my machine and dual booted manjaro. Once installed, manjaro wasn't showing up in the grub so I ran `update-grub`. Now manjaro shows in the grub, but is only able to boot in advanced options initramfs fallback` kernel.

I was going to try to reinstall grub, but I wanted to ask here before trying anything else.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd ask at their forum. Its pretty good, I've got help there a few times

Comment: I installed manjaro alongside ubuntu and manjaro won't boot after I ran `update-grub` in Ubuntu. I think grub in Ubuntu doesn't know how to boot manjaro correctly. So I used grub in manjaro to update grub and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
The point is *update-grub* generates a menu entry for Manjaro, but it needs 2 *files* in the initrd line:

- `/boot/amd-ucode.img`
- `/boot/initramfs-5.8-x86_64.img`

but it generates only the former.

It's a know [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1635781) and you can solve it by following the answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628206/how-can-i-boot-into-arch-linux-using-initramfs-in-ubuntus-grub/842802#842802)

That's: there are two files that need to be modified; I've tested it on my Lubuntu 16.04.1 and Manjaro Linux.

In Ubuntu:

1. File `/usr/lib/linux-boot-probes/mounted/40grub2` there is a function `parse_grub_menu()` that doesn't handle all initrd parameters. You need to modify 'case "$1" in ... initrd)':

   a) remove assignment

   ```
   initrd="$(echo "$2" ...)"
   ```

   b) add two lines in place of the removed one:

   ```
   shift 1
   initrd="$(echo "$@" | sed 's/(.*)//')"
   ```
2. File `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` within a `for` loop fix the assignment of `LINITRD`:

   ```
   for LINUX in ${LINUXPROBED}; do
   ...
   LINITRD="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 5 | tr '^' ' '`"
   ```

The first fix takes all available *initrd* info for Manjaro into account. The second fix cleans up the generated *initrd* line by changing some `^` characters to spaces.

Comment: Please try to use syntax properly in next answer